# Web API Controller Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I have an N-tier project that am trying to test the API controller but the flow is a little bit more complex which makes me ask for some opinion from you guys... Please any suggestion will be appreciated so much...

I'm getting an error

> Object reference not Set to An Instance Of An Object

This is my test class and method that get all fake symptoms

```cs
[TestClass]
public class SymptomsControllerTest 
{

    private Mock<IAdministrationManagementService> _administrationManagementServiceMock;
    SymptomsController objController;
    IList<SymptomObject> listSymptoms;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _administrationManagementServiceMock = new Mock<IAdministrationManagementService>();
        objController = new SymptomsController(_administrationManagementServiceMock.Object);

        listSymptoms = new List<SymptomObject>() {
         new SymptomObject() { Name = "Head1" },
         new SymptomObject() { Name = "Head2" },
         new SymptomObject() { Name = "Head3" }
        };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Symptom_Get_All()
    {
        //Arrange
        _administrationManagementServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetSymptoms()).ReturnsAsync(listSymptoms);

        //Act
        var result = objController.Get() as List<SymptomObject>;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual("Head1", result[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Head2", result[1].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Head3", result[2].Name);

    }

}
```

the service am trying to communicate to looks likes this

```cs
 public Task<IList<SymptomObject>> GetSymptoms()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var _uow = new HomasUoW())
                {
                    var entities = _uow.Symptoms.GetAll().Where(x => x.isDelete == false);

                    if (entities.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        IList<SymptomObject> list = new List<SymptomObject>();
                        foreach (var entity in entities)
                        {
                            var obj = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<Symptom, SymptomObject>(entity);

                            obj.Name = entity.Name;

                            list.Add(obj);


                        }

                        return list;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.NonExistingObjectRetrievalError);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        });

    }
```

and the API Controller looks like this

```cs
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var symptoms = _Service.GetSymptoms();

            if (symptoms != null)
            {
                return Ok(symptoms);
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Please look at it carefully and check if am missing any thing that is not allowing the test to pass.

Comment: Am thing if the problem is from the Mapping inside the services

Comment: Which object is `null`?

Comment: that is what I cant really detect since i can't use Break Point on test

Comment: Why can't you debug your tests?  That sounds like a more significant problem to solve first.  Using a debugger should be the *first* step in diagnosing a problem.

Comment: the null exception is coming from this line of code `Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> the null exception is coming from this line of code `Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 3);`

Clearly the `result` object is `null`.  Look at how you get that object:

```
var result = objController.Get() as List<SymptomObject>;
```

Even if `Get()` returns something, the behavior of the `as` keyword is such that when you try to interpret an object `as` the wrong type, the result will be `null`.  You're trying to interpret that object as `List<SymptomObject>`.  But what does `Get()` return?

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

You can't cast `IHttpActionResult` to `List<SymptomObject>`.  You have two options:

1. Your WebAPI controller should return a `List<SymptomObject>` (which I would say is probably the better approach, but there are more considerations to be made outside the scope of the code shown), or;
2. Your test should validate the `IHttpActionResult` being returned.

Comment: To be precisE: it should return an OkResult<Task<IList<SymptomObject>>>. I don't see why you would advocate for the first solution thou'gh, since IHttpActionResult is so handy

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: For re-use and unit testing, returning the actual type of resource being returned is pretty handy too.  Perhaps we've encountered different issues in solving different problems, but just returning the model itself has worked really well for me.

Comment: No doubt that having the actual type is useful of course, but that is also contained in the IHttpActionResult. It's simply wrapped in a response that also indicates the result of the call (`Ok<T>`, `BadRequest<T>`, etc). But sure, both are valid approaches of course.